# Populate Select2 multiple select box with user selected data after Laravel 4 redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 multiple select box on a form, for users to select the countries they have previously visited. I'm using Laravel 4 and when the form is submitted, it then validates all form fields and redirects back to the form if any validation errors have occurred - repopulating the form with the users previous input ( using Input::old('???') ).

My questions is how can I reapply the users previous selections to the Select2 multiple select box, using the data stored in Input::old('countries[]') ?

Where in my JavaScript code would I add the ID's of the users previous selections?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#inputCountries').select2(); // How do I add selections?

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to provide the array of IDs of countries as an argument of selected items. Might need to use one of array_keys to get just the IDs passed into the selected items array.

Comment: With an array of IDs, where would I put this in my JS code to make the selections again. There doesn't appear to be much in the way of documenting this stuff.

Comment: Actually, the selections would be all done with HTML, not JS (just like a multiple dropdown), and running Select2 would only create the nice look to it.

So like this: 

{{ Form::select('countries[]', $countries, Input::old('countries',$user->countries()->lists('id')), array('multiple','id'=>'countries','placeholder'=>'Choose countries')); }}